# Существуют ли множественные исключения в с++ в одном блоке?

Tags: c++, исключения

Есть ли возможность в си++ реализовать перехват двух и более исключений в одном блоке? Пример:

```
try{
...
}
catch(int bar, string &foo)
{
....
}
```

Или необходимо делать перехват каждого исключения отдельно?

```
try{
...
}
catch(int bar)
{
...//здесь например тот же код, что и в следующем блоке catch
}
catch(string &foo){
...
}
```

Одинаковый код конечно можно вынести в функцию. Но есть ли возможность отлавливать 2 и более исключения в 1 блоке catch?

Comment: `catch(string("foo"))` - это вообще что-то странное... может, вы имели в виду `catch(string& foo)`?

Comment: То, что вы написали, просто не имеет смысла.

Comment: Можно чтобы не повторять код, вызывать другое исключение в двух catch, которое будет обработано внешним try

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, по-моему такое решение только запутает код.

Answer (score 3):

Можно отлавливать либо исключение одного типа, либо все (любого типа).

В первом случае надо не забывать, что объект производного типа *является* объектом базового. И в этом случае можно использовать те же виртуальные функции и прочие возможности ООП.

Во втором - учитывать, что здесь перехватываются **все** исключения, если они не были перехвачены до того. Так что `catch(...)` - ultima ratio, который должен использоваться последним.

Answer (score 2):

Такого синтаксиса нет, надо писать отдельные `catch` блоки.

Answer (score 0):

Такая возможность есть, но обязательное условие: классы исключений должны иметь общий базовый класс. Его-то и нужно указать в блоке `catch`. Т.е. с обычными `int` и `std::string` не прокатит, но если сделать базовый класс типа `MyException` и от него наследников `MyExceptionInt`, `MyExceptionString`, то чтобы поймать и обработать оба исключения достаточно написать:

```
catch(MyException& e) {
    // обрабатываем на основании виртуальных функций MyException, например.
}
```

Comment: то есть указать:
catch(BaseException& e) 
{if (typeid(e)==Parent1) ...}. Или можно использовать виртуальные функции?

Comment: тогда уж и про catch(...) сказали бы =)

Comment: @free_ze `catch(...)` тоже полезно, но информацию из исключения получить сложнее.

Comment: @rubeno4ka запись `catch(...)` ловит исключения *любых* типов.

Comment: @alexolut, разве есть такая возможность получить исключение из catch(...)?

Comment: @alexolut про catch(...), я в курсе, но если надо именно конкретные исключения перехватывать, то он не подходит. По крайней мере узнать что за ошибка произошла, я не знаю как.

Comment: @rubeno4ka есть [`std::current_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/current_exception), который можно потом передать дальше по инстанциям, но можно ли оттуда выделить тип, надо смотреть в конкретной имплементации. В общем случае - нельзя, т.к. тип `exception_ptr` - не определен явно в Стандарте.

Comment: @alexolut, спасибо буду знать о такой возможности. Но как я понимаю, она не потокобезопасна и в случае повторного исключения мы теряем предыдущее исключение.

Comment: @rubeno4ka одновременное существование двух исключений это уже довольно странная ситуация, в частности поэтому нельзя кидать исключения в деструкторах.

Comment: @rubeno4ka Еще один способ ловить разнотипные исключения в одном catch. Если вы ищите полный аналог из Java: catch(Exception1 | Exception2 | Exception3 ex), то в C++ такого нет, нужно писать различные catch.